# How to write a pandas function that allows me to read in a number into an equation and output results to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a mathematical equation like so:

```
number = x
mult = x * 7
div = mult / 3
add = div + 4
answer = add - 6
```

How do I write a function, that reads in every number between 1 and 10, and output the result to a pandas data frame like this one:

```
x     answer
1      0.333
2      2.666
3      5
.      .
.      .
.      .
10      21.333
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(1, 11)})
df['answer'] = df.x * 7 / 3 + 4 - 6
#general solution if possible change operators
#df['answer'] = ((((df.x * 7) / 3) + 4) - 6)
print (df)
    x     answer
0   1   0.333333
1   2   2.666667
2   3   5.000000
3   4   7.333333
4   5   9.666667
5   6  12.000000
6   7  14.333333
7   8  16.666667
8   9  19.000000
9  10  21.333333
```

With function:

```
def func(first, last):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(first, last+1)})
    df['answer'] = df.x * 7 / 3 + 4 - 6
    return df

print (func(1, 10))
    x     answer
0   1   0.333333
1   2   2.666667
2   3   5.000000
3   4   7.333333
4   5   9.666667
5   6  12.000000
6   7  14.333333
7   8  16.666667
8   9  19.000000
9  10  21.333333
```

Comment: * And if you want to put it in a function (as OP requested), you could for instance call it with the range of numbers.

Comment: @user3471881 - Yes, not 100% sure what are inputs, so add both numbers